# Method references in Java 8: is overloading supported?

Tags: lambda, java-8, method-reference

Is there any way to refer to a group of methods in Java 8, which varies their signature the overloading way?

More precisely, I'd like this code to work:

```
public class OverloadingMethodRef
{
    public static void foo ( int x ) {
        System.out.println ( "An integer: " + x );
    }

    public static void foo ( String x ) {
        System.out.println ( "A String: " + x );
    }

    /**
     * I want it to work without this
     */
//  public static void foo ( Object x ) {
//      if ( x instanceof Integer ) foo ( (int) x ); else foo ( ( String ) x );
//  }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        // Compile error, it wants a precise reference to one of them
        Consumer<Object> c = PolymorphicMethodRef::foo; 
        foo ( "bla" ); // despite it could get it
        foo ( 1 ); // and here too
    }
}
```

I cannot afford to add `public static void foo ( Object x )`, because I have a lot of methods to pass to another method and I don't want to write wrappers. So far, I could do this only via reflection (which can receive `param.getClass()`), but the methods I have to call have varying arguments (>=1) and every time I need to put them in an array, plus their types in another.

Comment: Yes polymorphism is supported. And also no - that's not polymorphism, that's **overloading**. And no, there is not - Java wires method calls to specific method overloads at compile time.

Comment: Whops! Yes, I mean overloading, I fixed the question, thanks.

Comment: It is indeed not possible to get method reference that would act as if it pointed to overloaded method. Best you can do is add another method like `void foo(Object x)` and get a consumer out of that, but it will still always call that exact method (with Object parameter) and never will resolve to anything else.

Comment: @MikhailProkhorov, as I have written, I don't want to write that kind of wrapper, because I have many different foos to call :-) and hence writing all those wrappers would make reflection more practical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method references support overloading using the same rules as with ordinary method invocations. When you have a `Consumer<Object>`, you can pass arbitrary `Object` instances to its `accept` method, i.e. you can write

```
Consumer<Object> c = /* some expression producing it*/; 
c.accept(new JButton());
// or just
c.accept(new Object());
```

and since you can’t write

```
foo(new JButton());
// or
foo(new Object());
```

when you only have a `foo(int)` and a `foo(String)`, it’s also impossible to write

```
Consumer<Object> c = OverloadingMethodRef::foo;
```

which would construct a `Consumer` pretending to accept arbitrary `Object` instances.

If you are willing to accept Reflection overhead, you can use

```
Consumer<Object> c=o -> {
    try {
        new Statement(OverloadingMethodRef.class, "foo", new Object[]{o}).execute();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
};
c.accept(42);
c.accept("bla");
```

<sup>(this refers to `java.beans.Statement`)</sup>

Of course, this can fail at runtime when being invoked with an unsupported argument type.

Comment: Thanks @Holger. In practice, this is missing from Java :-) I understand it's in line with static type checking, but still not very good (accepting arbitrary object, binding at run time and raising a warning at compile time would be better to me).

Re: reflection, I'm using `org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.MethodUtils`, simpler syntax.